# Problem with RecordCount in MS-access 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to understand what I have done wrong in the code snippet below. I am reading some session records with a specific Client ID and putting the records returned into LineGrid for further processing. The problem is with the line NoL = Rs.RecordCount The query returns multiple lines (I can see this in the development environment). So in one example NoL is assigned the value 1 even although Rs.Recordcount is larger (3). I can check this directly in the debug environment.

At risk of stating the obvious even is record count is 3 only the one row is inserted into LineGrid

```
Dim Db As DAO.Database
Dim RsCL As DAO.Recordset 'ClientSession

Dim NoL As Integer
Dim LineGrid As Variant

Set RsCL = Db.OpenRecordset("Select * From ClientSession WHERE ClientID = " & CDID)
If RsCL.EOF Then
    MsgBox ("Nothing to Invoice")
    Exit Sub
    End If
'RsCL.MoveFirst
NoL = RsCL.RecordCount
LineGrid = RsCL.GetRows(NoL)
RsCL.Close
```

I have tried

1. Changing the data type of NoL to Long - No effect
2. Putting Rs.Count in the place of (NoL) in GetRows property - No effect
3. If I replace NoL with a value e.g. 100 then the code works fine then all records are loaded into LineGrid but I don't have the true record count.
4. I have tried moving the record pointer with .movefirst property ( you will note that line is currently commented out) - No effect

Ultimately I need LineGrid to contain the data from the table and NoL to have the true record count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a recordset, not all of the records are loaded immediately. In order to force all of the records to load, you need to move to the last record before moving back to the first one:

```
    RsCL.MoveLast
    RsCL.MoveFirst
```

Regards,